# EADDRINUSE Exception in node js while cluster.fork()

Tags: node.js, port, node-modules

I am running node js in EC2 instance, and sometimes while restarting the EC2, I am getting an `EADDRINUSE` error. I am using `cluster.fork()` to fork the process on the number of CPUs.

The main problem in my use case is, I am not able to replicate this scenario locally. This is coming very frequently in EC2 while auto-deployment.

Can someone help me understand what is causing the issue here?

I am suspecting this `cluster.fork()` is creating the problem.

Code:

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
 var num = require('os').cpus().length;
 for(int i=0; i<num; i++){ 
    cluster.fork();
 }
}
```

PS: *I know this error comes when the process is already running and we can manually kill the process using the command. but that solution might not work here. When we deploy, we get a new instance hence and we check the port availability so chances are very very less that port is already occupied by some other service.*

Comment: make sure the port on which the server is run is not utilized by any other process. Also, post your code, please.

Comment: updated the code, I am suspecting some issue while folk().

Comment: `folk()` or `fork()`? there is no such method `folk()` if i am not wrong.

Comment: @AnkurSoni sorry typo, its fork()

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code to understand how the cluster's `fork()` is being used to utilize multi-cores.

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const cluster = require("cluster");
const totalCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
 
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Number of CPUs is ${totalCPUs}`);
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
 
  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < totalCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
 
  cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    console.log("Let's fork another worker!");
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  const app = express();
  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
 
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
  });
 
  app.get("/api/:n", function (req, res) {
    let n = parseInt(req.params.n);
    let count = 0;
 
    if (n > 5000000000) n = 5000000000;
 
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      count += i;
    }
 
    res.send(`Final count is ${count}`);
  });
 
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

Comment: It's the same thing, will not solve the error.

Comment: check if port is utilised by any process.